# Array passing to a method in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

As far as I know, in C++ when you pass a non-pointer object to a method, it makes a copy of it to work with in the method. However in my program below, I pass a copy and yet my method actually edits the original character array. Why is this working? :/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 void Reverse(char s[], int sizeOfArray)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        s[i] = 'f';
    }

}
int main()
{
    char c[3] = {'g','t','r'};
    Reverse(c,3);
    for (int t = 0 ; t < 3; t++)
   {
      std::cout << c[t];
   }
    return 0;
 }
```

NOTE:

The output is fff

Comment: Because in C++, arrays are _not objects_. It does work with class and structure types containing arrays though, which is exactly what the C++11 `std::array` is.

Comment: On a side-note, this is the same in C. In C it's common to pass structures by pointer, but they _can_ be passed by value there too.

Comment: @JanHudec Depends on how you define the term "object". According to the C++ standard, arrays are definitely objects.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot copy arrays by passing them to functions. The array "decays" into a pointer. Check for yourself by printing the variables' typeid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void Reverse(char s[], int sizeOfArray)
{
    std::cout << typeid(s).name() << "\n";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        s[i] = 'f';
    }

}
int main()
{
    char c[3] = {'g','t','r'};
    std::cout << typeid(c).name() << "\n";
    Reverse(c,3);
    for (int t = 0 ; t < 3; t++)
   {
      std::cout << c[t];
   }
    return 0;
 }
```

Result:

```
char [3]
char *
```

Moral of the story:

Use `std::vector`.

---

Edit: I should mention that the exact result of the typeid *name* is implementation-defined. "char [3]" and "char *" is what I get with VC 2013. But the underlying issue is the same on every compiler, of course.

Comment: or use std::array in C++11 (if you want a fix sized array)

Comment: Yes, but I still think one should use std::vector if there are no special requirements, and consider std::array only if it's needed (but then, it's better than raw arrays in roughly 99% of all cases, of courses).

Answer (score 0):

void Reverse(char s[], int sizeOfArray)

Reverse(c,3);

**>call by value**

**>call by reference**

here you are doing call by reference operation that means you are passing address of c to int s[]

> you are passing a reference of c to reverse function. this is called call by reference not call by value. thats why reverse function overriding your original input

Answer (score 0):

Because `char s[]` is actually `char *` pointing to the first element of array.
It means your function `Reverse` gets the first arg pointer but not copy of array.

If you want to get copy you should use `memcpy` first and pass new (copy) array to function.

Answer (score 0):

C-array cannot be passed by copy.

It may be passed by reference as `void Reverse(char (&a)[3])`
or by its decayed pointer as you do `void Reverse(char a[], int size)` 
(which is the same as `void Reverse(char* a, int size)`).

You may use `std::array` (C++11) to have a more intuitive behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

if you declare an array then the variable holds the base address of that array, so here `char c[3]` means `c` holds the base address of the array `c[3]`.

so, when you are passing `Reverse(c,3);` actually you are passing the base address.